# Boundry String in a Multipart MIME?

Tags: networking, protocols

How can you ensure that the Boundary String in a Multipart MIME does not appear accidentally in the content itself and marks an incorrect border there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the definition of MultiPart Content type https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

"... The encapsulation boundary MUST NOT appear inside any of the encapsulated parts. Thus, it is crucial that the composing agent be able to choose and specify the unique boundary that will separate the parts."

So is the task/burden of the agent creating the content to insure that the random string doesn't coincidentally occur inside. If it does find it, then a unique delimiter must generated until it passes muster.

Comment: I'll add that it would be possible, but an amazing coincidence if a random string does appear in the content itself. I wouldn't be surprised if some lazy implementations don't actually check, although they ought to do so.

Comment: And in looking further, I realized that there's no requirement that the string be random.

Comment: The most recent specification of the multipart media type is in RFC 2046 section 5.1, especially section 5.1.1.  For additional advice, see section 6.7 of RFC 2045 (in the paragraph starting with "Since the hyphen character").

Comment: Per Peter O.s reference - ref https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc2045/?include_text=1